# Make our own "Application unavailable" page

Tags: cloudbees

We need to completly stop our application during an upgrade because we have to execute a critical mysql script.

So our application will be turned off during several minute then Cloudbees will display a basic "Application unavailable" page. We would like to change this by our own page with our logo, like we did it when we have our own apache/tomcat server. Could it be possible ?

Btw, is there a page with active sessions like we have in the Tomcat manager ?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment there isn't an easy way to do that - but there is a feature which will be out there soon to make that easy (amongst other things).

The only way currently is to have an app (another app) - which is your simple page - you then remove the domain name from your current app and add it to that app (etc) - messy, but possible.

In terms of sessions, the operations tab of the web console shows information like that, there is also the newrelic console which provides other insights.

Comment: See the answer below (?) this one (from Nicolas !).

Answer (score 4):

You can use beta-featured [blue-green](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html) support to switch your application to another instance running a "maintenance" page

with latest SDK (1.3.1), run `bees app:proxy:update -a acme-maintenance -al www.acme.com` to reconfigure the http router for www.acme.com to the maintenance app, then let your application run the mysql upgrade script, and restore the router configuration after completion.

Warning : this feature is in beta and subject to instabilities / API changes

Comment: +1 We're already using this blue-green functionality and it works great! :)